# Custom Google search url that excludes certain sites

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut, google-custom-search

I am a doctor and frequently search for colleagues. I am almost never a potential patient looking to make an appointment. The least useful results to me are those from [vitals.com](http://www.vitals.com) and [healthgrades.com](http://www.healthgrades.com).  However, occasionally I need them. So the obvious thing to do is append -site:healthgrades.com -site:vitals.com to each google search I do looking for a particular doctor. How do I code that in a url? If I know the URL then I could make a custom search in my browser and call it up with a nice short keyword.

I looked at Google Custom Search but that insists on starting with some particular sites. I want to search the whole internet but exclude just two sites.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Google Custom Search to achieve this. Set up your custom search engine, then go into the "Sites" settings and add the top level domains (*.com, *.org, etc.) to the "Included sites" section. Add whatever sites you wish to skip in the "Excluded sites" section. Good to go!

[image: Here's a screen shot of my setup]

Google states that:

> Adding "top-level domains" such as '*.com', '*.travel/*' is not
> permitted in Google site search.
> (http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71826)

but I have not had any issues doing so - not sure if this may change in the future but it seems to work at present!

Comment: Surely there is a way to feed text to a url. I would much rather learn the url coding. That way I can be more flexible and nimble with new search parameters.

Comment: @user505946 interesting, but is it possible to have an excluded set of url with the free edition of google custom search ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so here is how I changed Chrome's Google search settings (copied original search URL and created new search type in search engines settings):

```
{google:baseURL}search?q=-site%3Avitals.com%2B-site%3A%2Bhealthgrades.com%20%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}
```

The other problem I got is duplicate results like for "[Primary care physician in 60654](https://healthjoy.com/find-a-doctor/pcp/chicago-il-60654/)" page in search results.

[Google search results example for the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0BFt.png)

Sometimes google returns multiple pages from one domain, which I don't like, but could influence on this only by additional javascript :)